Facing an issue while fetching the records from the DB
I am facing an issue with DB. WHile i am fetching records from the DB i am not able to get the records. My issue is I have written a code for mongoDB to fetch the data and insert and that is working fine. Now i am trying to modify the same code for postgres. here requiremnent is i have one json payload as input and in the code i have a filter object which filters some unique keywords from the json payload so after filtering that keyword in filter_object then it process for the insertion in the postgresDB.
Code
def save_auth(inp_obj, context, response, is_valid):
    solution_id = context.get('solution_id', 'claimsol16')
    db_conn = DBProvider.get_instance(db_name=solution_id)
    """Insert data into MongoDB"""
    db_table = context["db_table"]
    # DB Update
    logger.info("Updating auth data to DB")
    caseID = inp_obj['RX_payload']['caseID']
    filter_obj = {'CRX_payload.caseID': caseID, "run_sequence": context["run_sequence"]}
    current_date = datetime.now().date()
    process_date = current_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    db_data = {"run_sequence": context.get("run_sequence", ""),
               "process_date": process_date,
               "updated_ts": datetime.now(),
               "execution_id": context.get("dag_execution_id", ""),
               "response": response,
               "is_valid": is_valid
               }
    existing_case = db_conn.find(table=db_table, filter_obj=filter_obj)
    if existing_case:
        db_conn.update(table=db_table, filter_obj=filter_obj, update_obj=db_data)
    else:
        db_data['CRX_payload'] = {'caseID':caseID}
        db_conn.insert(table=db_table, rows=[db_data])
    inp_obj.pop("_id", "")
    return True

THis is the code what i modifed . So here in this filter_object "filter_obj = {'CRX_payload.caseID': caseID, "run_sequence": context["run_sequence"]}" this is working for mongo is fine but while i am trying for postgres i am facing this issue operation fialed while fetching record from the DB and this one "cannot extract element from an object". SO here my question is how can we modify that filter_object to fetch and insert the record in postgresDM
